# Automapper and IoC

Tags: ioc-container, ninject, automapper

After reading the blog post by Jimmy Bogard on [AutoMapper and IoC](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/05/11/automapper-and-ioc.aspx), I tried to implement something similar using Ninject as IoC. So what I understand from this is an IoC will provide a **Singleton Instance** for **IConfiguration** which you use to define object Mapping.

```
Dim config as IConfiguration = Kernel.Get(Of IConfiguration)
Config.CreateMap(Of Source, Destination)
```

So later I wrote a test to check what does the **Mapper** static class do different. In the following test I compare 2 different instance of **IConfiguration** and **IMappingEngine** and the test passed.

So I'm trying to find out whats the purpose of using IoC with AutoMapper when the **Mapper** static class does the same thing i.e. provide singleton instance of IConfiguration everytime.

```
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test()
       Dim c1 As IConfiguration = Mapper.Configuration
       Dim c2 As IConfiguration = Mapper.Configuration

       Dim e1 As IMappingEngine = Mapper.Engine
       Dim e2 As IMappingEngine = Mapper.Engine

       Assert.AreSame(c1, c2)
       Assert.AreSame(e1, e2)
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a component containing your mappings that is configured as a singleton, you can make sure that a component configured as transient get their dependencies (mappings) fulfilled by injecting the mapping component.

You wouldn't have to initialize the mappings elsewhere by any other means.

And if you have transient components, you would be sure that the mapping initialization code is run once since that component is configured as singleton and then injected.

I haven't done it like this myself (my components are mostly singletons), but it sounds like a pretty good idea.